# fork react-native (with native modules) component locally

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-ios

im new with react native.

have a project , helloworld

```
root/
    /android/
    /ios/
    /node_modules/
                 /githubLib1/
                            /android/...
                            /ios/...
                            ...
    /src/
...
```

so my question is how can i fork 'githublib1' to 'githublib2' and place it to a root level and then connect to a react native ?

i did copy and place on root
but when i do 'react-native link githublib2' the engine want to use /node_modules/ for search only

so for andriod i did this

```
rootProject.name = 'heeloworld1'

include ':githublib2'
project(':githublib2').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,         '../githublib2/android')

include ':app'
```

please let me know how , maybe me need to use another practice for this